# Vue.js Firebase - Get data inside method and how to loop through?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuefire

i am trying to make a file.txt with my data form my firebase realtime database, but first i need to push my data into my method **downloadfile()** and loop throw. but i can't find the solution! can someone help me?

```
let app = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let db = app.database();

let booksRef = db.ref('books');

export default {
name: 'App',
firebase: {
 books: booksRef
},
data () {
  return {
    newBook: {
     author: '',
     title: '',
     genre: ''
    }
  }
},

methods: {

downloadFile: function() {

  // Need all my data from firebase
  // and loop throw my data

  //btw: i am using npm save-as to make my file.txt and this works.

  let blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/plain;charset=utf-8' })
  saveAs(blob, 'file.txt')

  }
 }
}
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: The Firebase documentation covers the basics of this fairly well, and if you need it the [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/) is a easy way to get started too.

Comment: i am trying for 48 hours, and looking into Firebase documentation and youtube videos, but i can't make it work